# Twig iterate with variables

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, loops, twig

I have an array like this:

```
array['a'] = {x => 1, y => 2...}
array['b'] = {x => 5, y => 7...}
```

I need to iterate over the array, but in each case I need to enter only in the 'a' or 'b' which I choose.

```
{% for i in main %}
    {% set id = i.getId %}
    {% for j in array.id %}
         //do something like j.propertyA ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The fail is always get the error: "The key 'id' for array with keys 'a', 'b'... does not exist"

If I force writting:

```
{% for j in array.a %}
```

The program works fine always with array.a but I need to works with all automatically.

Any idea? Thanks :)

Comment: How do you know that you'll choose 'a' or 'b' ?

Comment: Can you add expected output, please?

Comment: Fixed with {% for j in array[id] %} Using '[]' instead of '.' works fine! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `{% for j in array.id %}` to `{% for j in array[id] %}`

This is because you're trying to access "`id`" (as is written) directly from array (and isn't defined). With `[id]` your variable is substitued with its value and so your call will not fail

Answer (score 0):

I think you need array|keys twig filter. See more: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/keys.html.